# How to select context words/characters surrounding an <a> tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am processing HTML from a web crawler using BeautifulSoup. The HTML is run through filters that "simplify" the HTML, stripping and replacing tags so that the the document contains only `<html>`, `body`, `<div>`, and `<a>` tags and visible text.

I currently have a function that is currently extracting URLs and anchor text from these pages. In addition to these, I would like to also extract the N "context words" preceding and following the `<a>` tag for each link. So for instance if I have the following document:

```
<html><body>
<div>This is <a href="www.example.com">a test</a>
<div>There was a big fluffy dog outside the <a href="www.petfood.com">pet food store</a> with such a sad face.<div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Then if N=8 I want to get the following 8 "context words" for each link:

```
'www.example.com' --> ('This', 'is', 'There', 'was', 'a', 'big', 'fluffy', 'dog')`

'www.petfood.com' --> ('fluffy', 'dog', 'outside', 'the', 'with', 'such', 'a', 'sad')
```

The first link (`www.example.com`) has only two words preceding before hitting beginning of document, so those two words are returned, as well as the 6 following the `<a>` tag to make the total of `N=8`. Also note that the words returned cross the boundary of the `<a>` tag's containing `<div>`.

The second link (`www.petfood.com`) has `N\2` = 4 words that precede it and 4 that follow it, so those are returned as context. That is, if possible the N words are split between those preceding and those following the `<a>` tag.

I know how to do this if the text is within the same `<div>` as the link, but I cannot figure out how to do this across `<div>` boundaries like this. Basically, for the purpose of extracting "context words", I want to treat the document as if it were just a single block of visible text with links, ignoring containing divs.

How can I extract the text surrounding `<a>` tags like this using BeautifulSoup? For the sake of simplicity, I would even be satisfied with an answer that just returns the N characters of visible text preceding/following the tag (and I can just handle tokenizing/splitting myself).

Comment: In your first example (`www.example.com`), the link text `a test` is included in the output. But in the second example `www.petfood.com`, the link text isn't in the output. Would you like the link text to be included or not?

Comment: Thanks @glhr. That was a typo. The link text was not supposed to be included. I am already extracting anchor text, and only want the context words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that takes the whole HTML code and N as input, and for each occurrence of an `<a>` element, creates a tuple with the link URL as first element, and list of N context words as second element. It returns the tuples in a list.

```
def getContext(html,n):
    output = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.findAll("a"):
        n_side = int(n/2)

        text = soup.text.replace('\n',' ')

        context_before = text.split(i.text)[0]
        words_before = list(filter(bool,context_before.split(" ")))

        context_after = text.split(i.text)[1]
        words_after = list(filter(bool,context_after.split(" ")))

        if(len(words_after) >= n_side):
            words_before = words_before[-n_side:]
            words_after = words_after[:(n-len(words_before))]
        else:
            words_after = words_after[:n_side]
            words_before = words_before[-(n-len(words_after)):]

        output.append((i["href"], words_before + words_after))
    return output
```

The function parses the HTML with BeautifulSoup, and finds all the `<a>` elements. For each result, only the text is retrieved (using `soup.text`) and stripped of any newline characters. The whole text is then split into two parts using the link text. Each side is parsed into a list of words, filtered to get rid of any spaces, and sliced such that a maximum of N context words are extracted.

For example:

```
html = '''<html><body>
<div>This is <a href="www.example.com">a test</a> 
<div>There was a big fluffy dog outside the <a href="www.petfood.com">pet food store</a> with such a sad face.<div>
</div>
</body></html>'''

print(*getContext(html,8))
```

Outputs:

```
('www.example.com', ['This', 'is', 'There', 'was', 'a', 'big', 'fluffy', 'dog'])
('www.petfood.com', ['fluffy', 'dog', 'outside', 'the', 'with', 'such', 'a', 'sad'])
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55609756-link-context

Edit: note that a pitfall of this implementation is that it uses the link text as a separator to distinguish between `before` and `after`. This might be a problem if the link text is repeated in the HTML document, somewhere before the link itself eg.

```
<div>This test is <a href="www.example.com">test</a>
```

An easy workaround is add special characters to the link text to make it unique, for example:

```
def getContext(html,n):
    output = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.findAll("a"):
        i.string.replace_with(f"[[[[{i.text}]]]]")
        # rest of code here
```

will turn `<div>This test is <a href="www.example.com">test</a>` into `<div>This test is <a href="www.example.com">[[[[test]]]]</a>`.

Comment: Wow, this looks great. I can't test this in depth at the moment, bc I have to drive someone to the airport, but will do so when I return later and mark as accepted if it works out (as I expect it does from looking at it). Thanks!